# Search keywords in one mysql column by using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am newcomer here and appreciate your cooperation.

For example I have MySQL table with one field "title" where some row = "**How to install Windows 8**"

```
//Search
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE title LIKE '%Ho%' AND title LIKE '%windo%'
```

I exactly need to return "How to install Windows 8" from MySQL when I type in search form keywords: "Ho windo"

The above query is not working, could you please suggest the right way?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Difference between `post_title` and `title`?

Comment: Sorry Gents, just updated my question

Comment: It's ok. What is your output?

Comment: Try `SELECT title FROM mytable WHERE title LIKE '%Ho%' OR title LIKE '%windo%'`

Comment: I can`t see any errors in dbug mode, so search result show me that nothing found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT title FROM mytable WHERE title LIKE '%Ho%windo%'
```

Comment: Well yes, but he wants this dynamicly. `'%'.str_replace(' ','%', $input).'%'`

Comment: That is true though ^^

Comment: I didn`t use php code because Im pretty sure that something wrong in SQL query. Anyway your answer is useful for me! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can return single column from mysql using `column_name` instead of *.

```
SELECT `title` FROM `mytable` WHERE `title` LIKE '%Ho%' AND `title` LIKE '%windo%'
```

For dynamic search you can use `explode()` function in php to build WHERE query.